# Recuparar valor da Celula do table e passar para uma Segunda tela PHP

Tags: php, table, paginação, onclick

Ola,

Estou com uma necessidade e tenho uma grande dificuldade com PHP, alguma consegui me ajudar, estou criando um table com informações do banco de dados, e dentro de uma celula estou colocando um Onclick para abrir uma segunda tela para mostrar o detalhamento.
Preciso que quando o usuario clique em uma celula eu receba o valor da mesma na outra pagina.
Segue abaixo o código.

```
            <?php
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tabela where id = '$_SESSION';";
        $BSG = $CONNEXT->prepare($SQL);
        $BSG->bindValue(':usr', $USER_, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $BSG->execute();

        while ($RESP = $BSG->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            //header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7');
            $percentagem = $RESP[quantidade] / $_erb * 100;
            $ta = "";
            if($RESP[taRaiz] != ""){
       //// preciso recuperar esse valor que esta na celula e abrir em outra
       //// pagina para efetuar uma outra consulta, coloquei google, mas eu 
       //// criar uma outra pagina para receber
                $ta = "<td href=\"\" onClick=\"window.open('http://google.com','Janela','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=600,height=300,left=25,top=25'); return false;\">$RESP[taRaiz]</td>";
            }else{
                $ta = "<td class=\style3\></td>";
            }
            echo ("<tr>
                <td class=\style3\>$RESP[rota]</td>
                    $ta
                <td class=\style3\>$percentagem%</td>
                </tr>");
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes passar o valor através da Querystring, para isso basta mudar onde tens `google.com` e adicionar o valor a passar. Por exemplo

```
$ta = "<td href=\"\" onClick=\"window.open('http://google.com?taRaiz={$RESP[taRaiz]}','Janela','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=600,height=300,left=25,top=25'); return false;\">$RESP[taRaiz]</td>";
```

E na outra página, para o ires buscar, podes usar

```
<?php
$taRaiz = $_GET['taRaiz'];
// fazer o que precisas com esse valor
```

Comment: Valeu Funcionou